# percona server 5.7 database with Java

Tags: java, hibernate, docker, percona

I am using percona server 5.7 for db with docker. And MySQL cli for client.
I want to connect this database with Java application and docker is running. But I don't find any jdbc driver for this. I have tried with MySQL and Oracle driver but it didn't work.
I also want hibernate dialect for this.

Comment: Hi I have someone that can help you out, but they need a few more SO points before they can comment... so could you update your question with answers to these...

"You would connect the Java application to the MySQL DB, not the other way around. Could you please explain in more detail what exactly does not work? Any correlated errors or stack trace? Have you looked at the MySQL Connector as possible answer to this? "

If you could do that, once I have the info I can get my colleague from Percona to provide an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @percona-lorraine for your help.But Right now I am able to connect percona server with mysql client. Thanks.